# Clickable link in echo..how?

Tags: echo, clickable

I am using this code to display woocommerce custom field on frontend:

```
// DISPLAY Source Product URL ---------------------------------
           echo '<div class="woo_echo">';
            echo '<div class="woo_echo_inner">';
            echo "<span style='font-weight:600;'>". __( 'Source Product URL:</span> <span> ', 'woocommerce' )  . $_p_source_url ."</span>";
            $_p_source_url = get_post_meta($product_id, "_p_source_url", true);
           echo '</div>';
           echo '</div>';
```

It works very well but I would like

**. $_p_source_url .**

to be clickable link. Is it possible to wrap it with a tag?

*In this example source url is original url of scraped product not woocommerce product url.*

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this :

```
echo "<a href='$YOUR_LINK_PRODUCT_URL'>product</a>";
```

### EDIT

```
echo '<div class="woo_echo">';
echo '<div class="woo_echo_inner">';
echo "<span style='font-weight:600;'>". __( 'Source Product URL:</span> <span> ', 'woocommerce' )  . $_p_source_url ."</span>";
$_p_source_url = get_post_meta($product_id, "_p_source_url", true);
echo "<a href='$_p_source_url'>product</a>";
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks but I can not get it to work. Could you put it in my example please?

Comment: $_p_source_url is the url?

Comment: Yes $_p_source_url is url

Comment: Then, what you do not know? If you do this : `echo "<a href='$_p_source_url'>product</a>";` is not working?

Comment: You can not change it?

Comment: Yes I am stupid enough and can not implement your line into my block of code. Would you do it for me please? I am sure it would be so educational for me.

Comment: @Lestra See my edit.. I don't know if it's what you are looking for